# Unrecognized array error

Tags: c#, arrays

The following is creating a number of errors  i.e "B" is not recognized (as well as the other 20 letters and "File" is not recognized.

I can't see the problem here?

```
string[] correctAnswers = {B,D,A,A,C,A,B,A,C,D,B,C,D,A,D,C,C,B,D,A}; 
string[] studentResults = File.ReadAllLines("studentResults.txt");
```

Thankyou

Comment: `"B"` will be recognized, `B` won't be.

Comment: in first line code `string[]` should be `char[]` and `B` should `'B'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap them in double quotes:

```
string[] correctAnswers = {"B","D","A","A","C","A","B","A","C","D","B","C","D","A","D","C","C","B","D","A"};
```

**Edit :**

(Thanks to @goldenparrot) You need to add this namespace :

```
using System.IO;
```

to be able to use File.ReadAllLines(). either that or :

```
string[] studentResults = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("studentResults.txt");
```

Comment: And write proper `using` statement for `File`?

Answer (score 2):

```
const string A = "A";
const string B = "B";
const string C = "C";
const string D = "D";

string[] correctAnswers = { B, D, A, A, C, A, B, A, C, D, B, C, D, A, D, C, C, B, D, A };
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you have to enclose string literals in double quotes.

Now, if you want to maintain an array of *characters*, it is probably best to use a simple string instead of an array of strings, since strings are also iterable:

```
string correctAnswers = "BDAACABACDBCDADCCBDA";
```

Then something like:

```
foreach (char answer in correctAnswers) {
    // ...
}
```

Concerning the second part of your question, the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class resides in the `System.IO` namespace, so you either need a `using System.IO;` directive, or have to refer to that class by its fully qualified name, `System.IO.File`.

Answer (score 0):

write the letters inside double quotes, and use `@` for the path of the file.

```
string[] correctAnswers = {"B","D","A","A","C","A","B","A","C","D","B","C","D","A","D","C","C","B","D","A"};
 string[] studentResults = File.ReadAllLines(@"studentResults.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an array of `string`. As you know (or not), strings are in double quotes - " ". So in your problem, string[] should looks like:

```
string[] correctAnswers = {"B","D","A","A","C","A","B","A","C","D","B","C","D","A","D","C","C","B","D","A"};
```